# Convergence/Divergence of $\sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac 1n \left( \frac 2{3-(-1)^n} \right)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to figure out whether the sequence $\sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac 1n \left( \frac 2{3-(-1)^n} \right)^n$ either converges or diverges.  The 'inside' call $z$ will be such that $\frac 12 \le z \le 1$ and I know from that for a geometric sequence $-1 \le z \le 1$ the series converges, but then how does the $ \frac 1n$ come into play?

Comment: Well am I correct in saying the $\frac 1n$ does not converge, and the $z^n$ does converge?

Comment: I have realised that what I said was wrong, I have only confused you, I should probably go to bed :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the sum up into odd terms and even terms. The series becomes

\begin{align}
&\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \underbrace{\frac{1}{2k} \left(\frac{2}{2}\right)^{2k}}_{\text{Even terms}} + \underbrace{\frac{1}{2k-1}\left(\frac{2}{4}\right)^{2k-1}}_{\text{Odd terms}}\\
= ~~& \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{1}{2k} }_{\text{Diverges}} + \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2k-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2k-1}}_{\text{Converges}}
\end{align}

Since all terms are positive, and a subseries diverges, the given series diverges as well.

Comment: You need $2k-1$ to account for $n=1$.

Comment: Right-o. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Split the sum in two pieces over odd and even $n$ respectively, in order to get rid of $(-1)^n$. Your sum is the same as $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2k} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^{1-2k}}{2k-1}.$$